# How to get rid of horizontal scroll through adding $(window).width() to :before selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-class

[Here is my jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/0uq39v6g/) - I will explain what I want to do:

I've added 100vw to my section:before selector, but the **problem is that the horizontal scroll has appeared** (because 100vw adds scroll width to 100vw).

I figured that the way to get around the horizontal scroll issue is to apply $(window).width() to my section:before selector, this way my 100vw won't calculate the scrollbar in.

This is how I fiddle it should be done (but I don't know yet how to achieve this):

1. select :before element in jQuery
2. set :before width style to $(window).width()
3. horizontal scroll is gone.

Any ideas how to do it?

CSS:

```
section {
  width:500px;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0 auto;
    background: #222226;


}

section:before {
    content: 'this is my before';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index:-1;
    background: #ccc;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

jQuery (I know it is wrong because :before is not part of DOM model but his is the idea):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var window = $(document).width();

        $('section:before').css("width", window);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you're doing what you're doing but... set the overflow-x property to hidden;

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

It also might be worth it to set margin and padding to 0 in your :before element;

Comment: Or it does if you set overflow-x: hidden; to the body tag

Comment: The other option is to set  width: calc(100vw - .47rem); to section:before

Comment: It should also work to hide the overflow of the parent of section.